# Button won't log textfield values

Tags: ios, objective-c

So for my iOS app, if I delete the textfields and the code which grabs the text field values, the button works--in that it presents the indicated view controller..

But when I add these textfields and try to get the button to also Log their values, the button no longer works in that I push the button and nothing happens.

It's also worth mentioning that the code which creates these textfields is littered with "local declaration of "X" hides instance variable" warnings.. but i hear that's not too important (?)

Here's what's in the .h file:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextfield;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextfield;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked: (id)sender;

@end
```

And in the .m file:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "chooseFeedItemViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController ()
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize passwordTextfield;
@synthesize usernameTextfield;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView* v = self.view;
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //load Feed View button
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(177, 250, 100, 100);
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
    [button setTitle: @"submit" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor blueColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget: self
           action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [v addSubview: button];

    //username textfield
    IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 30, 200, 40)];
    usernameTextfield.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    usernameTextfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
    usernameTextfield.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    usernameTextfield.placeholder=@"create username";

    //password textfield
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, usernameTextfield.frame.origin.y+75, 200, 40)];
    passwordTextfield.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    passwordTextfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
    passwordTextfield.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    passwordTextfield.placeholder=@"create password";

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 80, 400, 400)];
    [view addSubview:usernameTextfield];
    [view addSubview:passwordTextfield];

    [v addSubview:view];


    }



    -(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    NSString *password = [passwordTextfield text];
    NSString *username = [usernameTextfield text];
    NSLog(@"username = %@ and password = %@", username, password);
    [self presentViewController:[ChooseFeedItemViewController new]
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

There's more to the .m file but it's irrelevant, i think

Comment: You should read up on Object Oriented Programming. Just because you name two objects the same does NOT make them the same object.

Comment: Those warnings are important. Don't ignore them, they would have led you to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`alloc init` give you brand spanking new objects, NOT references to your existing ones. Use `self.usernameTextField` to access your existing object.

Comment: can you point out where you are referring to? I only alloc init those textfields once.. at least that I can see

Comment: I assume they are outlets from a xib. If so, you don't need to alloc init them. If not, then don't use the IBOutlet keyword.

Comment: Notice how you create new text fields, add them as subviews, but then never assign them to your properties!

Comment: They are not from a xib. I took out the IBOutlet and IBAction keywords and all the errors/warnings went away however the button still does not work.

I now use self.usernameTextfield in the buttonClicked body.
I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I've gotta agree with @Duncan on this one. You are in over your head. Start over and read some tutorials.

Comment: found the reason and it wasn't what you might think. the position of the submit button. i moved it way up to the top and it worked.. though i'm confused as to why that is the case? when I move the button further down (still clear of both the keyboard and the textfields, it doesn't work..

Comment: Maybe behind some other view that is clear? I'd still be surprised if your existing code managed to output the correct NSLog text.

Answer (score 0):

You are in completely over your head.

Do not create new text fields. Set up your text fields in Interface Builder (IB), and control-drag from your IB fields into the header of your program to create IBOutlets. Then use those IBOutlets in your code.

It does matter, and matter a great deal, that you are getting "local declaration of "X" hides instance variable" warnings.

The problem is that you have instance variables for your text fields, and then you have code that creates an unrelated set of text fields and installs them in your form. If you also created text fields in IB, then you've got duplicates of each text field, but only one is connected to your IBOutlet instance variables. If you never created the text fields in IB, then your outlets point to nil.

You should stop, find a good book or set of video tutorials on Objective C and/or iOS development, and go through the exercises to learn the basics. Your lack of understanding is more than a few forum questions is going to fix.